# setspace package not working in TeX Live

Tags: texlive, setspace

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and using the texlive-full apt package. I've tried this in TeXmaker and TeXstudio and I get the same errors in both, and I've tried it on Overleaf and it works just fine, so the problem must be with TeX Live.

I am able to import the setspace package without any errors or warnings, but if I try to use any of the setspace methods, the compiler says they're undefined. Here's an example and a relevant part of the log file.

I just don't know why this package is working on Overleaf but not my machine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{May 2020}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\setstretch{2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.5.15)  20 MAY 2020 01:22
entering extended mode

...

)) (./setspace.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `doublespacing' for package `setspace'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \setdisplayskipstretch 

l.9 \setdisplayskipstretch
                          {}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \setstretch
                {2}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \setstretch{2
                  }
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Try with `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` and remove `\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\setstretch{2}`

Comment: Why are you using a local copy of setspace? and not the version from your latex installation?

Comment: @daleif I'm not sure what you mean. I never installed setspace independently. It's not even clear to me that it's possible to add packages when the texlive installation comes from a package manager.

Comment: @MadyYuvi It also doesn't understand options for setspace. I've edited my example to include that.

Comment: @NoName Hopefully you are using some non-standard version of `setspace`, please delete the `setspace.sty` from your local directory, then compile...

Comment: When we look at your log sniplet we see `(./setspace.sty)` this means that the version of the `setspace` package you are using is in the same folder as your `.tex` file and this it is being used not the one from the latex installation. Try renaming that local file such that it does not bother your compilation

Comment: @daleif Thank you! That file was from an older project that I had copied into the same folder. Moving them apart fixed it.

Comment: This is also a good thing to remember when you are debugging things like this. One can easily forget local copies. That's why when even I use local copies of a package (debugging or what ever) I always rename them first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sniplet of the log shows

```
)) (./setspace.sty)
```

meaning that you have a local copy of `setspace.sty` in your folder. Presumably this is a really old copy of `setspace` or a modified version.

Try renaming the local copy and see if that helps.